# Trying to center toggle button at the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center toggle button at the center of the page without changing any of its color property. When I try to change its position its color changes. I need help centering the button at the center of the page.

Comment: Please add a minimal code to reproduce what you are having now..

Answer (score 2):

You can apply  `transform` property to the `<div class="center">` to make it to the center of the page

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

body {
  background-color: #7a86cb;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: rgba(230, 231, 242, 0.15);
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
input:checked+.slider:before {
background-color:#E6E7F2!important
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <label for="toggle"></label>
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I am also trying to achieve this OFF STATE `Circle color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  Circle brder color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)` and ON STATE ` Circle color: #E6E7F2
  Circle border color: #E6E7F2` . Could you check?

Comment: I think the border color did not change when changing the state of the button

Comment: Yes in the on state the color is different, I tried to apply on    `input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: rgba(230, 231, 242, 0.15);
  border-color: #E6E7F2!important;
}` but it did not see any change.